# How to map fields in Hive for DynamoDb Amazon Console export?

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-dynamodb, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-emr

I am trying to load the DynamoDb export file which is taken from Amazon Dynamodb Web Console with "Import/Export" tool into Hive. But I couldn't map the fields properly because DynamoDB Web Console "Export" tool is using "ETX" "STX". 

Below is an example row ended with [LF]

```
Elapsed[ETX]{"n":"1477"}[STX]Device[ETX]{"n":"3"}[STX]Date[ETX]{"s":"2014-03-05T12:13:00.852Z"}[STX]Duration[ETX]{"n":"8075"}[LF]
```

What should be the query for this?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableNameHere (creationDate string, device bigint, duration bigint, elapsed bigint)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ???This is where i got stuck??? 
LOCATION 's3://abcdefg/ino/2015-05-28_12.22';
```

**UPDATE**

I have updated query but it didn't work again.

'\002' for STX
'\012' for LF

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableNameHere  (creationDate string, device bigint, duration bigint, elapsed bigint)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\002' 
                     LINES TERMINATED BY '\012'
LOCATION 's3://abcdefg/ino/2015-05-28_12.22';
```

Result for the query:

```
Elapsed{"n":"0"}   Device{"n":"3"}   Duration{"n":"1073876"}   Date{"s":"2014-01-27T00:52:25.491Z"}
```

So, now  how can i parse this data? I need to map fields.
Should i use a custom SerDe?

Comment: This is the format that i am trying to map its fields in hive: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-pipelinejson-verifydata2.html

Can it be done with a custom SerDe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's already a SerDe for that: https://github.com/lyft/dynamodb-hive-serde